# Función que determine que 2 listas son iguales

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo que realizar una función que me diga si dos listas son iguales: misma longitud y elementos de cada índice iguales.

Tengo hecho esto, pero siempre me dice que los elementos de cada índice son iguales aunque no lo sean, como tengo puesto en el código.

```
def listas_iguales(lista, lista2):
    if len(lista) == len(lista2):
        for i in lista:
            for x in lista2:
                if i == x:
                    print("Son iguales")
    else:
        print("No son iguales")
```

Ejemplo de llamada:

```
listas_iguales([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partiendo de la base que en condiciones normales basta con hacer:

```
if lista1 == lista2:
```

el problema es que  comparas cada elemento de la primera lista con todos los elementos de la segunda al usar dos `for` anidados, es decir, por cada elemento de la primera lista recorres la segunda al completo. Además tienes este condicional:

```
if i == x:
    print("Son iguales")
```

por lo que cada vez que exista un elemento en cualquier posición de la segunda lista que sea igual que el elemento de la primera lista sobre el que se va iterando se imprimirá `"Son iguales"`.

Debes comparar cada elemento de la primera lista solo con el elemento en la misma posición de la segunda, es decir, no debes usar dos ciclos anidados, sino uno solo que ha de recorrer ambas listas a la par, tienes varias formas de hacerlos pero lo normal sería usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) que te va a permitir ir obteniendo las parejas:

```
def listas_iguales(lista, lista2):
    if len(lista) == len(lista2):
        for i, x in zip(lista, lista2):
            if i != x:
                break
        else:
            print("Son iguales")
            return

    print("No son iguales")
```

El `else` está a nivel del `for`, no es parte de un bloque `if-else-elif`. En este caso el código contenido en el `else` se ejecuta solo **si el ciclo `for` no se completó**, y esto ocurre cuando ambos elementos difieren momento en el que `break` rompe el ciclo.

También puedes usar solo `return`:

```
def listas_iguales(lista, lista2):
    if len(lista) == len(lista2):
        for i, x in zip(lista, lista2):
            if i != x:
                print("No son iguales")
                return
        print("Son iguales")
    else:
        print("No son iguales")
```

Esto permite además que no tengamos que recorrer toda la lista siempre, en el momento que se encuentra una diferencia la comprobación termina.

Otra opción menos eficiente es usar `range` e indexado:

```
def listas_iguales(lista, lista2):
    if len(lista) == len(lista2):
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            if lista[i] != lista2[i]:
                break
        else:
            print("Son iguales")
            return

    print("No son iguales")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ampliando la respuesta de @FJSevilla, una solución *"funcional"* usando iteradores y bastante concisa:

```
def listas_iguales(lista1, lista2) -> bool:
    return len(lista1) == len(lista2) and
           all(x==y for (x,y) in zip(lista1, lista2))
```